# How to split a string based on a char

Tags: c++

I can get a substring from the following  line

```
string filename = C:\Shaders\Test\Model\source\scene.fbx"
filename.substr( 0 , filename.find_last_of('\') );
```

this would be the result

```
C:\Shaders\Test\Model\source
```

Now if i want to get the sub string from the last "\" to the end of the string that would be

```
scene.fbx
```

I am trying this line.

```
filename.substr(filename.find_last_of('/'), filename.size() )
```

but i am getting a crash.

Comment: You have to pick either `'/'` or `\\`` but one doesn't match the other...

Comment: `filename.substr(filename.find_last_of("\\"), filename.length() )`? I believe you want the `.length()` of the name, not its allocated `.size()`. Other than those issues, what you have looks reasonable.

Comment: @David C. Rankin sorry it was a typo i have corrected it now in the code.

Comment: You should try `auto lastSlash = filename.find_last_of('\');` so you can see what it's actually giving you (either a valid index or `npos`)

Comment: The `.find_last_of` member function takes `const basic_string& str` as the type to find chars from, see: [std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::find_last_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - It also has an overload taking a single `CharT`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica - yep, you are correct, form No. (4) will handle that nicely.

Comment: @Thank you it was a typo error as pointed by DavidC.Rankin , if you want to post an answer please do i will accept it.

Comment: `filename.substr(filename.find_last_of("\\")+1)` ended up working fine in my test. No `filename.length()` required as default end `pos` is `std::string::npos` which will be the end of the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you reversed the slash in your code, so there's no valid index to start with. Try this line instead:
`filename.substr(filename.find_last_of('\\'), filename.size() )`

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s = "C:\\Shaders\\Test\\Model\\source\\scene.fbx";
    cout<<s<<endl<<s.substr(s.find_last_of('\\')+1, s.length())<<endl;
    // As @David suggested in comments, you can omit `s.length()`
    cout<<s.substr(s.find_last_of('\\')+1);
}
```

Output

```
C:\Shaders\Test\Model\source\scene.fbx
scene.fbx
scene.fbx
```

Comment: You can omit `, s.length()` altogether as the default end `pos` is `std::string::npos`.

Comment: You're right. I was just being a little more verbose :)

Comment: Either way will work, I just generally let the defaults handle it if they will. Nothing wrong with your answer, just another something to consider `:)`